# DbVisualizer - duplicate links on References tab

Tags: postgresql, dbvisualizer

Any ideea why DbVisualizer 10.0.25 x64 (Win10) shows duplicate fks?

[image: DbVisualizer - duplicate FK link]

If I run this query

```sql
SELECT
    tc.table_schema, 
    tc.constraint_name, 
    tc.table_name, 
    kcu.column_name, 
    ccu.table_schema AS foreign_table_schema,
    ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
    ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name 
FROM 
    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
      ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
      AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
      ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
      AND ccu.table_schema = tc.table_schema
WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND tc.table_name='location'
```

It returns only one row.

This is happening with all my tables.

Comment: Could it be a bug with foreign key that point to the table itself?

Comment: Same issue with foreign key to another table.

Comment: Perhaps you should report that to the DbVisualizer guys.

Comment: This is a regression that will be fixed soon in 10.0.26.

Comment: Indeed, upgraded to 10.0.26 and the issue has been fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue.
It will be solved if you update to 10.0.26

Comment: Indeed, upgraded to 10.0.26 and the issue has been fixed. Thanks.